# Viewing a PHP after uploading on Filezilla

Tags: php, ftp, filezilla

This is my first time I use Filezilla and ftp. I uploaded my files.php. After I entered the hostname on address bar, I could see which files I had uploaded.
The interesting part comes here: When I clicked on index.php to view, It displayed only the html parts.

When I opened page source code, I saw that my php was commented, like this:

From what I had originally written:
`<?php include '/includes/php/menu.php'; ?>`

it became:
`<!--?php include '/includes/php/menu.php'; ?-->`

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it. Does any of the above has anything to do with host properties? From what I read, it supported php.

Comment: What editor is the php source being displayed in? You can set the default editor to view/edit files under `Settings->File Settings->Filetype Associations`. It will not have anything to do with host properties.

Comment: I checked the settings in Filetype Associations and the textarea there was empty. What should I add there so I can view my PHP sections?

Comment: See the answer below for my details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna thank all for your support. I am rather newbie in PHP and with you advice I have learnt a lot in the process. I have low rep so I can't give good rates to your answers.
The problem consisted in ftp, but later after changing some options in the host everything went OK. I guess working with PHP offline differs from online.

Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your host may support php, but that does not mean that PHP is enabled. You can perform a very simple test to find out.

Create a file named test.php and drop one line of php in it and save it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Upload the test.php file to the server and point your browser to it. It should output a bunch of information about the web server if PHP is working.

If not, check your host admin (cpanel) to see if you can enable it yourself. If you don't find it, just submit a ticket to have your host enable it.

PS: Remember to delete the test.php from your site as it is not great for security to leave it there.

Comment: I tied the test file but it showed only the same code you wrote above, no other information. I should remind you that I have uploaded the files in Filezilla and not in the server. I don't really know the difference here, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, PHP is not enabled on your web server. Open a ticket with your host to do this for you. It's a very simple thing for them to do, so it should not take long to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

It sounds like you don't have Includes module installed. If you are using Apache, make sure the Apache Module mod_include. To check if you have the module installed you should create a file called phpinfo.php and upload to your server root and it should include the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then load phpinfo.php in your browser and `mod_include` should be included in the section `Loaded Modules`. It would be highly unusual if it wasn't there, as it is the default to have it installed on most Apache systems. If you are not on an Apache server, you can still follow the above instructions.

---

<strike>You can set the default editor to view/edit files under Settings->File Settings->Filetype Associations. An example using Notepad is below. There is also a box to inherit system filetype associations and I have it checked.</strike>

```
txt C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
php C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
```

Comment: I want to view the page how it looks instead of the code. After I uploaded with Fillezilla, I went to the host and it displayed me what I uploaded. After I clicked on index.php (my homepage) so I could view how it looked, there were some parts missing, the parts that it had in common with other pages: these pages I created them in a different PHP file so I could include them. 
These parts don't show on my website. How can this be?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `Includes` module installed. If you are using Apache, make sure the Apache Module `mod_include` is installed. See my answer above for more details.